# PHP which compression function has equal output like mod_deflate?

Tags: php, deflate

I tried:

```
gzencode($contents, 9, FORCE_DEFLATE)
gzdeflate...
zlib_encode($contents, -15);// RFC 1951 - raw deflate
zlib_encode($contents, 15);// RFC 1950 - zlib
```

But none of them are suitable, because output is different.

And I'm talking about output, NOT headers!

I need deflate, not gzip.

Comment: `gzencode` should do the job. what's the problem?

Comment: can you expand on what your trying to do here

Comment: Ok, mod_deflate and mod_gzip doesn't work on my hosting because of provider. And no, I can't change hosting. I'm trying implement deflate for images, css, scripts...
So, all headers is ok. When I use gzencode($contents, 9, FORCE_GZIP) all is working.
But when I use gzencode($contents, 9, FORCE_DEFLATE) I get ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.

So, what's difference between deflate and gzip? I thought is headers and checksums difference only.

Comment: that's a different type of question, doesn't it? you should edit the post with your real question

Comment: Listen, I created 3 questions today because of "this is other type of question" and I still don't have answer. I just need to see it working. I don't want to be spammer

Comment: dont get shirty with the free help, if you expect any well help

Comment: Well, maybe people should not be a downers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [`gzcompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php). The use of the word "deflate" in the HTTP specification and content encoding is a misnomer. It really means zlib, which is a zlib wrapper around raw deflate data. `gzcompress()` produces zlib-wrapped deflate data.

From the HTTP 1.1 specification:

> deflate: The "zlib" format defined in RFC 1950 [31] in combination with
>   the "deflate" compression mechanism described in RFC 1951 [29].

So HTTP "deflate" == zlib. HTTP "deflate" != deflate.

For reference, `gzencode()` produces gzip-wrapped deflate data, and `gzdeflate()` produces raw, unwrapped deflate data.

Comment: Then there's something else that you're doing wrong. `gzcompress()` does in fact produce the format that HTTP specifies for "deflate".

Comment: So why it works with gzip then? I changed only one line. Responce headers with gzip are: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 22:22:44 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.2
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1983
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

And they must be equal with zlib

Comment: Did you change the requested content encoding? Did you look at what the client said it would accept? HTTP content encoding is a negotiation between the server and the client.

Comment: Change request content encoding? What do you mean? Clinent request headers are the same.
When I trying to use zlib, client(browser) just shows me error ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED, no information about the page on the Networks tab of the Dev tools.

Comment: Maybe you need to read more about how HTTP works. The client says what encodings it accepts with, for example, `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` (which also allows `identity`), and the server responds with the encoding it used, e.g., `Content-Encoding: deflate`, which should be one of the encodings that the client said it would accept. And of course it has to match the encoding you actually used.

Comment: Oh, I just misread about Content-Encoding: deflate. Sorry. And thanks.